# No Output Displayed?

Tags: html, asp.net

I used Infinite Scroll in Asp.net in c# using jquery. When I run this program it didn't display output.

**//This is my index.html Page**

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
            var j = 2;
            function ram() {
                abc(j);
                j++;
            }
            j = j;
            function abc(k) {//this function uses ajax to communicate with server
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'scroll.aspx/increasediv',
//here insertmethod is a function on page name datainsertusingjquery.aspx
                    data: "{'id':'" + k + "'}",//passing value of j in k and this k to function increasediv in code behind of scroll.aspx
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = response.d;
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                    }
                });
            }
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                    ram();
                }
            });
        </script>
```

**//This is my .aspx Page**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string increasediv(string id)
{
    string s;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\TestProjects\TeamB\3tire\scroll_may2\scroll_may2\App_Data\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Youtube from Movie where ID<" + id, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        sb.Append("<iframe src='" + dr[0].ToString() + "' alt='DotNet Team' height='300px' width='400px'></iframe><br/>");
    }
    s = sb.ToString();
    return s;
}
```

Can you tell me for what am missed ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not populate the initial value, you might need to do it using e.g.

```
$(window).ready(function(){
  ram();
});
```

See [demo](http://jsbin.com/revivera/1/edit)

There are few other things

- make sure that page is longer than 1 screen so, that the 'scroll' event is triggered
- selecting "... Movie where ID<" + id means that if you have 1,2,3,4... on first time it will select 1 row (id=1), on second scroll it will select 2 rows (id=1 and 2), etc. Maybe it makes sense to select "... where ID=" and select only 1 row which you could add to the existing list document.getElementById('para').innerHTML += response.d;
- j = j; is useless
- selecting "... Movie where ID<" + id makes code vulnerable to sql injections. Use sqlparameters instead